# Projecting a Tile Cache

Tags: tilecache

Can anyone tell me how can I project a TILE cache/PNG raster image from WGS1984 coordinate system to a different coordinate system?

Is it even possible to project a TILE cache?

Ive tried the Project raster tool and It didnt work. Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

You cannot edit your tile cache, it is in a read-only format. What you can do is to convert it to mbtiles (using portable base map) and then you can use GDAL to convert the mbtiles to Geotiff. You can now re-project your raster and after then you can create your tile cache back. In case you don't know how to create a tile cache, I have highlighted them here, On Arcgis click the file menu and navigate to share , select tile package. Then go to the search menu and search for "Export Tile Cache". This gives you the tile cache back.

Useful links:

[Converting tilecaches to Mbtiles](http://oruxmaps.forosactivos.net/t3350-a-tool-for-downloading-mbtiles-map-alternative-to-mobac)

[Convert mbtiles to geotiff (1)](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html)

[Convert mbtiles to geotiff](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Ftrac.osgeo.org%2Fgdal%2Fwiki%2FBatchConversionOfRasterFormatsOnDOS&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNFz-kE-3uiSbsITme1ltJc7SaRavA)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @underdark for the flag... if one time deal any of many options as above from cli is easiest.

If for a webserver that needs to read from a cache and reproject that from one to another Mapproxy can do this so long as massive the CRS/projections dont require massive processing:
https://mapproxy.org/docs/1.8.0/configuration_examples.html?highlight=reproject#using-existing-caches

or host on geoserver, mapserver, et al and etc as a service